# Accessing log files inside docker container

Tags: azure, docker, tomcat, logging, azure-web-app-service

I have a tomcat Docker image -- [source](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat)

This image has a sample war file that logs some data in a tomcat folder -- in the instance of this image in tomcat/logs

I am deploying this image as a web app using Azure containers -- and that works great, but I was wondering if there was a way to access that tomcat/logs folder?

I can FTP to the web app but I cannot access to the files in the Docker container.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: You could enable SSH in your image and then go to the Kudu Site -> SSH to check the files in the container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-custom-container?pivots=container-linux#enable-ssh. If this cannot be done, try enabling Diagnostic Logs.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to enable them. To enable application logging for Linux apps or custom containers in the Azure portal, navigate to your app and select App Service logs. In Application logging, select File System > In Quota (MB), specify the disk quota for the application logs > In Retention Period (Days), set the number of days the logs should be retained > When finished, select Save.

[image]

Then you can see container logs in your App Service > Monitoring > Log stream

You can use Kudu to view the logs -Linux/container apps:
https://.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logs/docker

You may also leverage App Service diagnostics.
To access App Service diagnostics, navigate to your App Service app in the Azure portal> In the left navigation, click on Diagnose and solve problems – Checkout the tile for “Diagnostic Tools” and “Availability and Performance” > "Application Logs" title.